# #ThumbnailPlugin How do I use meta-data while using the thumbnail-plugin?

Tags: docpad

When I use images from metadata in my layouts, I do it like this and it works:

```
    <img src="<%= @site.url %>/images/<%= @document.icon %>" alt="" title="">
```

When I use the wonderful working [thumbnail-plugin for DocPad](https://github.com/rantecki/docpad-plugin-thumbnails) like this, it works well, too:

```
<img src="<%= @getThumbnail("images/javascript.png", '128x128') %>" alt="">
```

Now I would like to combine both methods, to get the metadata from the document and let the thumbnail-plugin size it like I want. Is this possible? I tried something like this:

```
<img src="<%= @getThumbnail("images/<%= @document.icon %>", '128x128') %>" alt="">
```

I know the code above is crap, I am sorry... Just to explain what I would like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do what you're wanting to do.  The key point to realize is probably that when using eco, `<%=` puts you in 'coffeescript' mode and you can write any coffescript expression you want.

So to do what you want, you'd write this markup:

```
<img src="<%= @getThumbnail('images/' + @document.icon, '128x128') %>" alt="">
```

Comment: Thank you once again, Erv. It works. So I have to dig a little into coffeescript. It's sometimes difficult to wrap my head around all those different things like eco, coffeescript, javascript and sort everything out. Maybe Richard will include your snippet in his documentation for the plugin. I'll ask him right away.